# Dictionary value comparison when values appears as a list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionary where values are list of different length need to compare both the values of dictionary. In return need to see if any of the list in dict1 matches to dict2 values and prints the key of the respective dict. Also find the mismatch values in that particular value list print them

I tried multiple methods but got this error

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
dict1={'apple':[1,2,3,4],'banana':[2,4,7,8],'orange':[5,6,2,4,7]}
dict2={'1':[2,4,7,8,9,3],'2':[5,6,2,4,7,1],'4':[2,3,4,5,6]}

for keys,values in dict1:
    for keys,values in dict2:
        dict1[values]==dict2[values]
```

Result: for dict2 it will pick the key and from the list which values does not match

```
{'1':[1,7,8,9]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to iterate over dict with key and value then use the `dict.items()`.
It return the `dict_items` (list of tuples) which include `(key, value)`

Then you can unpack them and use in your for loop.

```
for key1, val1 in dict1.items():
    for key2, val2 in dict2.items():
        if val1 == val2:
            # now write your required code here
            print('Matched key1 {} key2 {}'.format(key1, key2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
dict1={'apple':[1,2,3,4],'banana':[2,4,7,8],'orange':[5,6,2,4,7]}
dict2={'1':[2,4,7,8,9,3],'2':[5,6,2,4,7,1],'4':[1,2,3,4]}

for key1, val1 in dict1.items():
    for key2, val2 in dict2.items():
        print("Matching {}:{} and {}:{}".format(key1, val1, key2, val2))
        diff = list(set(val1).symmetric_difference(val2))
        if len(diff) != 0:
            print("Differences found {}:{}\n".format(key2, diff))
        else:
            print("The two lists matched\n")
```

**Output**

```
Matching orange:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7] and 1:[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3]
Differences found 1:[3, 5, 6, 8, 9]

Matching orange:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7] and 2:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 1]
Differences found 2:[1]

Matching orange:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7] and 4:[1, 2, 3, 4]
Differences found 4:[1, 3, 5, 6, 7]

Matching apple:[1, 2, 3, 4] and 1:[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3]
Differences found 1:[1, 7, 8, 9]

Matching apple:[1, 2, 3, 4] and 2:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 1]
Differences found 2:[3, 5, 6, 7]

Matching apple:[1, 2, 3, 4] and 4:[1, 2, 3, 4]
The two lists matched

Matching banana:[2, 4, 7, 8] and 1:[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3]
Differences found 1:[3, 9]

Matching banana:[2, 4, 7, 8] and 2:[5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 1]
Differences found 2:[1, 5, 6, 8]

Matching banana:[2, 4, 7, 8] and 4:[1, 2, 3, 4]
Differences found 4:[1, 3, 7, 8]
```

I have updated the list to generate a case for matching the lists and it matches for this case `Matching apple:[1, 2, 3, 4] and 4:[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: let me try this